# What's the meaning of "register hits"

Tags: meaning

Here is a line from an American drama[Manifest]:
**[I ran the tags on the screen caps of the buses that you sent me. The State Police's automatic license-plate reader got all five of them heading south after they left the hangar. The entire caravan registered multiple hits: tunnels, highway on-ramps. Five buses, until they exited the thruway, then one of them disappeared.]**
What confused me was the meaning of **"hits"**.
I don't know the rules of American high way driving... Does it mean something like toll stations?

Comment: We need more context. But it doesn't seem to have anything to do with tolls, unless by "highways" what was meant was "turnpikes".  What is the American drama?

Comment: Agree that more context is required. At a guess I would say that the caravan is registering hits on monitoring systems such as ANPR (i.e. registering positive matches).

Comment: [Please cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/36187). The context helps users better understand the meaning. Include the name of the drama (not just "American drama"), with the episode name/number, a timestamp, a summary of the situation, and larger portion of the text/dialogue.

Answer (score 5):

This is a great example of why we ask for context. In this case the preceding lines in the show make it clear what "hits" means:

> I ran the tags on the screen caps of the buses that you sent me.  The State Police's automatic license-plate reader got all five of them heading south after they left the hangar. The entire caravan registered multiple hits: tunnels, highway on-ramps. Five buses, until they exited the thruway, then one of them disappeared.
>
> — [source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=manifest-2018&episode=s01e06)

"Hits" is used in the same sense we speak of "hits" on Google or any similar search: they're instances of the license-plate reader identifying the buses being tracked.